# Bus error: 10 using malloc on struct pointer, C

Tags: c, malloc

I'm trying to malloc some memory for a struct pointer. The code compiles fine, but when I run it I get bus error: 10 after the user enters their name. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong so would appreciate any help!

Thanks in advance :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(){

    struct name{
        char *first;
        char *last;
    };

    struct name *user;

    char temp[10];

    printf("What is your first name?\n");
    scanf("%s", temp);
    user->first = (char*) malloc(strlen(temp)+1);
    strcpy(user->first, temp);

    printf("What is your last name?\n");
    scanf("%s", temp);
    user->last = (char*) malloc(strlen(temp)+1);
    strcpy(user->last, temp);

    printf("Your name is %s %s\n", user->first, user->last);

    free(user->first);
    free(user->last);

    user->first = NULL;
    user->last = NULL;

}
```

Comment: Ask yourself, *where does `user` point to?* Because it's uninitialized when you do `user->first = (char*) malloc(strlen(temp)+1);`.

Comment: besides use `scanf("%9s", temp);` to make sure you don't overwrite the buffer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't allocate memory for `user` to point to.  So it is left uninitialized and attempting to dereference that pointer leads to [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to allocate memory for `user`, just as you did for its fields:

```
struct name *user = malloc(sizeof *user);
```

Comment: Ah I see! Thank you :)